# how to interpret robustness result

Tags: r, robust-standard-error, metafor

I ran a multivariate meta-analysis to account for dependencies of effect sizes using `metafor` and then I also applied a robustness check using the `robust` function of `metafor`. However, I am not sure how I should interpret the results of this robustness check. Can anyone help with this?

Here are the results of the multivariate meta-analysis

```
> output5_IN_3[[1]]

Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 226; method: ML)

Variance Components:

            estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed    factor 
sigma^2.1  0.0417  0.2042     43     no        ID 
sigma^2.2  0.0341  0.1846    226     no  ID/study 

Test for Heterogeneity:
Q(df = 225) = 13585564.4636, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate      se    zval    pval   ci.lb   ci.ub      
  0.2277  0.0385  5.9169  <.0001  0.1523  0.3031  *** 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And here are the results of the robustness check

````
 robust(output5_IN_3[[1]], cluster = study, adjust = TRUE, clubSandwich = FALSE)

Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 226; method: ML)

Variance Components:

            estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed    factor 
sigma^2.1  0.0417  0.2042     43     no        ID 
sigma^2.2  0.0341  0.1846    226     no  ID/study 

Test for Heterogeneity:
Q(df = 225) = 13585564.4636, p-val < .0001

Number of estimates:   226
Number of clusters:    226
Estimates per cluster: 1

Model Results:

estimate     se¹   tval¹  df¹   pval¹  ci.lb¹  ci.ub¹      
  0.2277  0.0247  9.2125  225  <.0001  0.1790  0.2764  *** 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "robust" function is not a robustness check. It is simply a different way of calculating the standard errors of the regression coefficient. Specifically, a Huber-White "sandwich" style heteroscedasticity-consistent variance estimator is used. The theory around this estimator is well developed, and in general it provides a more robust uncertainty interval and significance test than with standard modeling error terms. You should just report the output from the "robust" call, and clarify in your methods that you used a robust error estimate to handle possible heteroscedasticity (among other things, but that being a chief concern in meta-analysis).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation